# How bad is new Thread().sleep compared to Thread.sleep in terms of CPU and memory utilization?

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling

I'm aware that sleep should be accessed in a static context. However I need more inputs so I can defend this to the management. Most of the legacy code that I'm handling now uses new Thread().sleep instead of Thread.sleep.

How bad is this?

```
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
    new Thread().sleep(5000);
}
```

compared to this?

```
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

EDIT:

```
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println("Free memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println("===========================");
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
        new Thread().sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Used memory: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));
        System.out.println("===========================");
    }
    System.out.println("Total memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println("Free memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println("===========================");
    System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " milliseconds");
```

Result (new Thread().sleep):

```
Total memory: 5177344
Free memory: 4990904
===========================
Used memory: 186440
===========================
Used memory: 205136
===========================
Used memory: 205136
===========================
Used memory: 205136
===========================
Used memory: 205136
===========================
Total memory: 5177344
Free memory: 4972208
===========================
Time elapsed: 24938 milliseconds
```

Result (Thread.sleep):

```
Total memory: 5177344
Free memory: 4990904
===========================
Used memory: 186440
===========================
Used memory: 186440
===========================
Used memory: 204848
===========================
Used memory: 204848
===========================
Used memory: 204848
===========================
Total memory: 5177344
Free memory: 4972496
===========================
Time elapsed: 24938 milliseconds
```

Comment: In both cases the sleep will be several orders of magnitude longer than the "overhead" of `new Thread()`. Still, I agree with what EJP says below.

Comment: @all sorry for my answer.. i didn't saw that java tag.. i answered in context of C#.. My mistake :(

Comment: @Shekhar: don't fret, it's not personal. Downvotes are strictly because the answer didn't apply here.

Comment: yeah i know.. should have noticed that.. anyway good point is i got Peer Pressure badge.. something for loosing 8pts :)

Comment: It looks like it would be better to use `Thread.sleep(25000)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is just illiterate programming, simple as that. Same applies to calling any static method that way, it's not confined to Thread.sleep(). It imposes pointless space and time costs, but worse it betrays a major conceptual misunderstanding on the part of the programmer. I wouldn't devote much energy to going back and fixing all the occurrences but I would certainly do something about re-educating the personnel concerned.

Comment: Does it really take that much energy just to replace all the occurences of "new Thread().sleep(...)" into "Thread.sleep(...)"? Even without IDEs, `find` + `sed` can do the job!

Comment: @Bruno: it's true, but sometimes confusing the VCS history for such a thing is not worth it. "Who was the last guy to touch that code before it broke?"

Comment: @Bruno: yes it can, if there are dozens or hundreds of occurrences and they are scattered over many files that are all checked out to other developers. It can actually be completely impossible.

Comment: @Joachim: "confusing the VCS history" and "turning bad code into good code" are two different things.

Comment: @Bruno: but they can easily happen at the same time. (Also: a `Thread.sleep()` call (even when executed correctly) is rarely "good code" ;-))

Comment: thanks for the answer and comments, I need to profile this for the numbers.

Comment: @Bruno: I mean the subject under discussion: calling a `static` method via the class its located in and not via a variable or (worse) an explicitly created instance of the class.

Comment: @EJP, read my answer (it's worse than just creating the new Thread())

Comment: @bestsss I don't see the point of this comment. I said it imposed space and time costs, and your post relates directly to calling new Thread().

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what has already been said: if you are already rewriting some legacy code, probably this is the most idiomatic and straightforward way to express sleep (you can of course use different time units):

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

How bad is it?  Probably not really bad from a performance perspective.

My understanding is that the expensive part of thread instantiation only happens when you call `Thread.start()`.  However, quite a bit of work happens during construction of the `Thread` object:

- initializing a bunch of fields,
- doing security checks,
- etcetera.

If you want evidence that it is a significant performance issue, then you'll need to profile your application.  (And I have my doubts that it *would* be significant.)

But it shouldn't be hard / expensive thing to fix ... unless you are in a world where *every* change is hard / expensive ... or unless your application does some seriously weird / broken things with ThreadGroups or inheritable ThreadLocals.

My main complaint would be that it is as ugly as the north end of a south-bound cow.  On a par with calling `new String(...)` all over the place.

---

I don't think your benchmark shows much.  The overhead of creating an unwanted Thread is likely to be in the area of a micro-second or so.  That's down in the noise.  Besides, your methodology for measuring memory usage is plain wrong.  The `totalMemory()` and `freeMemory()` methods give you memory stats that were recorded at the last GC run.

Comment: I have updated my post. I'm not sure if my way to measure it is right. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: during `init` the thread also registers itself as unstarted in the ThreadGroup which later leads to some issues...

Comment: @bestsss - I know.  Try explaining that to @EJP who is convinced there are no possible issues.  (IMO, anything an application does with ThreadGroups counts as "weird".)

Comment: applications on their right own no, but I do use ThreadGroup, myself. They are truly useful to track all the threads created past some point. They can impose max thread priority or even enhance the access to some static data to become based on the calling ThreadGroup. Since all the threads are available, they can be interrupted or even stopped, when the context of that 'application' is being destroyed. JBoss uses ThreadGroups, AWT and JavaWeb Start too; they are not worthless by far, dunno about 'weird'.

Comment: I've used ThreadGroups too ... but only for "framework level" things.

Comment: @Stephen C your speculations about what I am convinced about aren't valid deductions from the available evidence.

Answer (score 2):

**Actually it costs quite a bit:**

`new Thread()` is, in fact, an expensive call (not as much as `Thread.start()`, of course) but involves stack crawl, few synchronized blocks, few security checks, copy of the inherited thread locals and so. Under security manager it can get messy as well.

Prior to 1.3 the unstarted threads used to cause a severe memory leak... Now it's still an issue: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4229558 ThreadGroup reports wrong threadCount AND can become negative... but worst of all still causes  leak since the ThreaGroup won't puff (`destroy()`) after all threads get exit unless discarded by hand. The latter can be problematic as it requires to wait for all the threads to exit properly and after that call `destroy()`. Sounds simple but it's an actual problem for managed environments (namely the container).

**Edit** Since it's not clear ThreadGroup can be subclasses in order to override `uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)` and deal with the throwable. That makes the ThreadGroup class holding reference to the classloader and the issue is real. (not just a minor single object leak)

Overall unstarted threads have been bugging Java since its inception, you'd be better off replacing the code. It will take less time than I wrote the reply (mostly to shed some light to the believed free initialization).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand how Java handles static methods correctly, the first method will still call the static version of sleep() in addition to creating a new thread object. It's almost always better to use the second because it's understood that the method is static by calling it with respect to the class rather than to an instance.

if you're able to quickly find/replace these code statements, I'd say it's worth it. However, since both codes work I don't think this is something you should be overly worried about.

Comment: the one thing I've learned about computers (actually, most things in general) is never to say never, and never say always because someone just might come along and prove you wrong :P

Comment: So *prove* me wrong. Find me a case where calling a static object via a temporary object constructed for that purpose and no other is better than calling it statically.

Comment: someone != me, personally I can't think of any case where this would be true

Comment: @EJP - Construction of a plain Thread has side-effects that are detectable via the ThreadGroup.  The existence of inherited ThreadLocals could also impact.  But these are all highly unlikely scenarios, and probably involve significant existing brokeness in the application.

Comment: @Stephen C: there are no documented semantics involving ThreadGroup. Everyything I can see there refers to 'active' threads. Ditto ThreadLocal actually. I'm also still curious what the other version of sleep() actually is other than 'the static version'.

Comment: @EJP, *So prove me wrong*, you can read my answer. I have had first hand experience with exactly that, not destroying ThreadGroups, it's not nice.

Comment: @Stephen C you haven't provided a case where creating the object is better. Only where it is different, but we knew that.

Answer (score 1):

They do the same thing, and the method is static in both cases.

In `new Thread().sleep(5000);`, it's not clear what's actually going on, because the static method is being called from an instance.  That is, it's functionally identical to `Thread.sleep(5000);`, which has the benefit of being transparent.

It's also not clear that it's the current thread that will be put to sleep, so someone could legitimately puzzle whether it's the current thread or a newly created thread which will be put to sleep; it's actually the current thread.

If the first style is allowed, you could come have something like:

```
Thread anotherThread = new Thread();
```

then later on have

```
anotherThread.sleep(5000);
```

This too is identical to `Thread.sleep(5000);`, and actually puts the current thread to sleep.  But it's not at all obvious what's going on.

The style in the second case is preferable because it avoids these pitfalls, and any performance penalty associated with creating a new instance.  It should therefore be used at all times.