# Java: do I need to protect a Thread object from the Garbage Collector?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, garbage-collection

After

```
{
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
}
```

is the Thread object a candidate for the GC?

Comment: To clarify - this is more a theoretical question than a practical one - I don't believe that even if the spec allows it, anyone would implement a JVM where the Thread object would be a candidate for GC in the above scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's started, it's not eligible for GC - the code that's running can ask for `Thread.currentThread()`, after all.

If you just created it but didn't start it, like this:

```
{
    Thread pointless = new Thread();
}
```

then I suspect it *would* be eligible for GC - but it's pretty unusual to create a thread without starting it. (I guess an exception could be thrown before you got round to starting it...)

Comment: The only real use case for unstarted `Thread` object I know of are shutdown hooks using [`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Comment: "If it's started, it's not eligible for GC - the code that's running can ask for Thread.currentThread(), after all." That's my intuition, but I can't actually find a conclusive argument from the specs - for example, could an implementation use weak references to return the current thread?

Comment: The spec says that objects which are accessible from any running thread are retained, this includes the Thread itself.

Comment: @Mark: If it were stored as a weak reference, what would `Thread.currentThread()` return if it had been collected? null?

Comment: @Peter do you have a reference for me?

Comment: @Jon that rules out weak references indeed

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html see the section on "Types of Reference Objects"

Comment: @Jon, a started thread has a global JNI reference (i.e. not collectible, whatsoever) and a reference in its ThreadGroup. An unstated thread causes "funny" issues that have been polluting (leaking) java since its inception. Even now upstarted threads are still an issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216781/how-bad-is-new-thread-sleep-compared-to-thread-sleep-in-terms-of-cpu-and-memory/5224087#5224087  + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216781/how-bad-is-new-thread-sleep-compared-to-thread-sleep-in-terms-of-cpu-and-memory/5217007#5217007

Comment: @bestsss: Right, that doesn't entirely surprise me :)

Answer (score 6):

No, its not eligible for Garbage Collection. Since, the thread is scheduled in the runnable queue by the Thread Scheduler( after calling `t.start( )`), it won't be eligible for GC.

One of the methods to check if the thread is still running or not is to call `thread.isAlive()`.

```
final boolean isAlive( )
```

The `isAlive( )` method returns true if the thread upon which it is called is still running. It returns false otherwise. 
In your case,you can always call `t.isAlive()` method, just to check whether the thread is alive or not.

When the thread stops or end's its lifecycle or is not yet scheduled to run (like Jon's Code Snippet), then it's eligible for GC.

Comment: "In your case,you can always call t.isAlive()" - the idea is that t is out of scope, but there should be some other reference to Thread that avoids the object from being GC'd

Answer (score 0):

You only need to protect a Thread if you want to retain it after it has finished.  It cannot be GC'ed while it is running (or anything the Thread uses)