# Will a thread get garbage collected if a thread in java is running and I do not own any Thread references to it

Tags: java, multithreading

As in the Thread.State is RUNNING and I set the Thread reference to null immediately after I start the thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351836/java-do-i-need-to-protect-a-thread-object-from-the-garbage-collector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the other question's answers, the thread would not be garbage collected.

By definition, an object is only elligible for garbage collection if it is not reachable by any *live thread* - and I'd consider a thread in running state a *live thread*. :)

From the Java 7 Spec (12.6.1):

> A *reachable* object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing
>   computation from any live thread.

And internally I'm sure some part of the JVM still has a reference to that thread, the scheduler for example.

Answer (score 1):

If a thread is running, the thread isn't eligible for Garbage Collection. A running thread has tasks so GC a running thread could have adverse effects on its task(s).

Comment: your answer is not relevant to question. the real answer is the thread class has reference to it, eventhough you dont have.